# How can I prevent git post-checkout hook from executing when I revert files?

Tags: git, post-checkout-hook

I have a git post-checkout hook that automatically re-compiles my Visual Studio project whenever I checkout to a different commit. This works great, but I have noticed that the hook also executes when I do a revert in TortoiseGit, both from the log-window and from the commit window (I right-click the file I want to revert and then click "Revert" in the pop-up menu). Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [post-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout),

> The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the previous HEAD, the
> ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have changed), and a flag
> indicating whether the checkout was a branch checkout (changing
> branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving a file from the
> index, flag=0).

You can test the 3rd parameter. If it's 0, do not compile. For example in Bash,

```
#!/bin/bash

flag=$3
if [[ "$flag" -eq 0 ]];then
    exit 0
fi
```

In Python,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

flag = sys.argv[3]
if flag == '0':
    sys.exit(0)
```